# Borel conjecture and arbitrary surface

Tags: reference-request, gt.geometric-topology, homotopy-theory, mapping-class-groups, surfaces

Before starting my question I want to write something that I already know.

> Borel Conjecture: Any homotopy equivalence between two closed
> aspherical manifolds is homotopic to a homeomorphism.

Now, my interest is in when our manifolds are surfaces. Here, I assume surface means connected and second countable, may or may not be orientable, may or may not have boundary, may or may not have punctures. In particular, I also consider two types of surfaces, finite-type or infinite-type, i.e. fundamental group is finitely generated or not.

Now, it is well known that any homotopy-equivalence between two closed surfaces is homotopic to a diffeomorphism. If the surface has boundary then one has to also require the homotopy-equivalence restricts to a homotopy-equivalence of the boundaries. A reference is Zieschang, Vogt and Coldeway, *Surfaces, and planar discontinuous groups*.

**From here my question starts.**

(1) Is any proper homotopy equivalence of surfaces is properly homotopic to a homeomorphism?

(2) Is there any sufficient condition on a homotopy equivalence (not necessarily proper) between two surfaces, so that it becomes homotopic to a homomorphism? If there is no such for the general case, is it possible to give such a sufficient condition in case our homotopy equivalence is in between two finite-type surfaces?

I am looking for references. Thanks in advance.

Comment: It should follow by equipping the surface with a hyperbolic metric and then straightening it out in the universal cover, I would have to think if there are subtleties but it is probably written down somewhere.

Comment: In the finite-type case, this is well-known. In the infinite-type case this is probably true since proper h.e. induces a bijection of the invariants of surfaces and the result is probably hidden in Richards' classification paper.

Comment: @MoisheKohan could you tell me a reference for the finite-type case?

Comment: See e.g. Theorem 8.8 in "Primer on MCG" by Farb and Margalit (although, they leave out some details). Let me know if you have trouble completing their proof. They state the result algebraically, but properness of the h.e. is what ensures that conjugacy classes of punctures map to conjugacy classes of punctures.